# vuelidate $touch() for same form creating/editing

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, vuelidate

I might have somewhat a tricky question and just want to be sure, I went the correct way.

To be precise, it's vuelidate 0x on vue 2 with good old boostrap-vue

Let's pressure we have a simple form, with the following validation

```html
<b-form>
.....
          <b-form-group
            id="title"
            label="Title"
            label-for="Title"
          >
            <b-form-input
              id="title-input"
              v-model="$v.form.title.$model"
              :state="validateState('title')"
              type="text"
            ></b-form-input>
            <b-form-invalid-feedback id="title-input-live-feedback">
              You must enter a title.
            </b-form-invalid-feedback>
          </b-form-group>
....
```

```js
    validations: {
      form: {
        title: { required }
      }
    },
```

So when we create this item. I do the following:

```js
      async createCompany() {
        if (!this.$v.$dirty) {
          this.$v.$touch()
        }

        if (this.$v.$invalid) return

        try {
          await this.storeCompany()
          ...
        } catch (error) {
          //
        }
      },
```

Now, I come back to the form, for example, to modify it. This means, the item has once passed the validation successfully, especially for required fields.

I noticed that in that sense $touch() is not necessary, unless you add new validations, which would always result in $invalid. Still, I wanted to have a solution that will also work for this case, just so I do not stumble over it in the future.

So, to come up with a "flexible" solution, I did the following:

```js
      async updateCompany() {
        if (this.$v.$invalid && !this.$v.$dirty) {
          this.$v.$touch()
          return
        }

        if (this.$v.$invalid) return

        try {
          let response = await CompaniesApi.update(this.id, this.form)
          ...
        } catch (error) {
          //
        }
      },
```

Basically, I first check if $invalid is true and if the form was not submitted (by checking for !this.$v.$dirty).

It works exactly as I want, no double, triple touches and no flickering in terms of validation changes due to touches.

What gives me a bit of a headache is the fact that I first check for this.$v.$invalid before I actually $touch().

Somehow, I thought it must be the other way around.

But I guess I misunderstood $touch() in a way that it's main job is really to show the $errors if needed (vuelidate only shows errors when $invalid and $dirty is set to true).

I know I could go the other way, disabling the submit button until the form is valid, but then I would need to add further elements to the form, e.g. make clear what is missing or maybe even $touch() the validation in the created() or mounted() hook.

Which however is also not what I want, because it would show errors to the user without any interaction.

So, the only solution I could find is the one described.

Did anybody else come across this? I mean, it does what I want, still would appreciate any feedback/ideas.